# How to connect to Linux USB serial gadget using Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, serial-port

I have an embedded device, on which I use the [USB gadget](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/) USB interface to either make it available as a mass storage device, or enable access over USB serial using the `g_serial` module.

While I can connect to the device using `modprobe usbserial` on Linux, how can I do it on Mac?  It only gives me the following:

```
$ ls /dev/tty.*
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem    /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
```

This is coming from the `dmesg`, not sure if it is related to the device:

```
USBF:   10410.547   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff801379c000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
USBF:   10416.549   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff801379c000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
USBF:   10417. 84   [0xffffff80138a7000] The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
USBF:   10422.789   [0xffffff80138a7000] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000)
```

Comment: Post here the result of `lsusb`, then this [article1](http://wiki.debian.org/usbserial) and [article2](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/howto:usbserial) might help.

Comment: Thank you for references, however I already wrote that I can connect to the device from Linux (when run natively, not in a VM). My main dev machine is a Mac OSX, but it does not seem to recognize the device or allow connection. The virtual machine (Parallels) on which I run Linux also does not allow me to "connect" the USB to the virtual machine.

Comment: There is no point in posting a question and then forgetting all about it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux (native) might have the right drivers, but not OS X.

It will help to know the output of `lsusb` and what happens if you try to follow [this article](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/howto:usbserial), for both native Linux and OS X.

The differences between the two might be instructive.